# Generalization of mean and standard deviation

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation

I remember from my student years that we could generalize mean and standard deviation in one formula. The formula defines a statistical characteristic over a positive natural number, called degree, far as I remember. When the degree is zero, you would get the mean (denoted $\mu{}_0$), when the degree is one, you would get the standard deviation (denoted $\mu{}_1$).

Unfortunately, I cannot find such a thing online. Is there such a number? What would that formula be.

Comment: You seem to be describing "moments", which have been discussed elsewhere on the site.  If this is not what you are talking about, please edit your question to help us narrow things down a bit.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your comment. Indeed, moment function is what I was looking for. I just couldn't find the right terms to search for it.